# Filter out some records on particular periods

Tags: sql-server

I have below tables structures,

**Trans Table:**

```
Trans_Id(PK)     User_Id(FK)       Arroved_Date
________________________________________________
1                   101             05-06-2016
2                   101             20-06-2016
3                   102             06-06-2016
4                   103             10-06-2016
5                   103             25-06-2016
```

**Table2:**

```
Id(Pk)           User_Id(Fk)       Start_Date         End_Date
__________________________________________________________________
1                  101              01-06-2016         15-06-2016
2                  103              05-06-2016         20-06-2016
```

I want to filter out the transaction, if the Approved_Date is not between the users Start_Date and End_Date of table2.

**Expected Result:**

```
Trans_Id
________
2
3
5
```

Comment: The expected result is not in line with the explanation of the expected result. Transaction ID #3 in `trans` table has no corresponding User's entry in `table2`

Comment: Yes. It might have in second table or not. if not, it should not be filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the expected results:

```
select t1.trans_id from t1
left join t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
where t2.id is null OR t1.Arroved_Date not between t2.Start_Date and t2.End_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation (not on the expected result) you need to just JOIN the two tables on the FK you pointed out, in order to get the relationship between the rows in the two tables.

Then just apply a `WHERE` clause to filter the row based on your condition:

```
select t.trans_id
from trans t
    inner join table2 t2 on t.user_id = t2.user_id
where t.approved_date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`SELECT Trans_ID
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.User_Id=Table2.User_Id
where Approved_date Between Start_Date And End_Date`

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but from you expected output..

```
SELECT distinct t1.Trans_ID
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on 1=1
where t1.Approved_date Between t2.Start_Date And t2.End_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.trans_id
FROM Trans tr
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON tr.User_id = t2.User_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
  OR t.Approved_Date IS NULL
  OR t2.Start_Date IS NULL
  OR t2.End_Date IS NULL 
  OR tr.Approved_Date <= t2.Start_Date
  OR tr.Approved_Date >= t2.End_Date
```

The null-checks are only needed if the columns are nullable. The left join can be changed to an inner join if every transaction has a corresponding row in table 2. The answer assumes that there is not more than one row in table 2 for each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT A.Trans_ID 
FROM TEMP A
JOIN TEMP B ON A.User_Id = B.User_Id
WHERE A.Approved_date BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
```